# Hiding a library within a library

Tags: c, interface, linker

Here's the situation. I have an old legacy library that is broken in many places, but has a lot of important code built in (we do not have the source, just the lib + headers). The functions exposed by this library have to be handled in a "special" way, some post and pre-processing or things go bad. What I'm thinking is to create another library that uses this old library, and exposes a new set of functions that are "safe".

I quickly tried creating this new library, and linked that into the main program. However, it still links to the symbols in the old library that are exposed through the new library.

One thing would obviously be to ask people not to use these functions, but if I could hide them through some way, only exposing the safe functions, that would be even better.

Is it possible? Alternatives?

(it's running on an ARM microcontroller. the file format is ELF, and the OS is an RTOS from Keil, using their compiler)

**[update]**

Here's what i ended up doing: I created dummy functions within the new library that use the same prototypes as the ones in the old. Linked the new library into the main program, and if the other developers try to use the "bad" functions from the old library it will break the build with a "Symbol abcd multiply defined (by old_lib.o and new_lib.o)." Good enough for government work...

**[update2]**
I actually found out that i can manually hide components of a library when linking them in through the IDE =P, much better solution. sorry for taking up space here.

Comment: Which operating system? Linkage features depend on your executable file format, which in turn depends on your operating system.

Comment: If people are programming against your libraries by looking at the symbol table then you have some serious software development process problems! Just don't expose the old lib's interface for developer use.

Comment: zneak: it's actually running on an ARM microcontroller. the file format is ELF, and the OS is an RTOS from Keil, using their compiler.

Comment: John: People aren't necessarily looking at the symbol tables, they just use the old library API functions which i would like to hide...

Comment: You don't need to hide the symbols in the library, just hide the header file from the developers.  :-)

Comment: Wyzard: That actually crossed my mind, but the function prototypes are insidiously spread out all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the GNU binutils, `objcopy` can prefix all symbols with a string of your choice. Just use `objcopy --prefix-symbols=brokenlib_ old.so new.so` (be careful: omitting `new.so` will cause `old.so` to be overwritten!)

Now you use `brokenlib_foo()` to call the original version of `foo()`.

Comment: Another option is to hook the old lib's functions, but that's not quite hiding.

Comment: this would have been my approach en lieu of the IDE solution, it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `libtool` to compile and link the library instead of `ld`, you can provide `-export-symbols` to control the output symbols, but this will only work if your old library can be statically linked. If it is dynamically linked (`.so`, `.dylib`, or `.dll`), this will not be possible.